# Calling third part class method

Tags: java, android

I have class A (extends Activity) which present a list of items from a table.

In class B (which extends activity) i am calling a method which eventually trigger class C (C extends a broadcast receiver).

In my class C i am updating a table in my DB in which class A gets the items to present.

My question is how to invoke a class A method after class C finish updating the table.

Making class A function static is quite impossible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If class C extends `BroadcastReceiver` and it is responsible for updating your database, once you update you can send a new `Broadcast` to let other parts of your application know that the table update is finished. You will need to register a receiver in the places you want to get the notification (i.e. in your A Activity class). If you only need to broadcast locally (only to your Application) you can use the new `LocalBroadcastManager` provided by the v4 support library. It will only broadcast locally and get rid of IPC overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Activities generally can't call methods from other activites. You need to find a different way for communicating between those classes. For example instantiate a dynamic receiver via [registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) in the one activity and send a broadcast in the other.

Apart from that, your questions seems to indicates your application architecture is not optimal. There is always only one activity visible at a time. Why do your activities need to communicate with each other?

Comment: He is not calling methods of one `Activity` from another `Activity`. Class C is a `BroadcastReceiver`, not an `Activity`. B triggers C, and then C has to let A know it is done.